# Joining & Merging two tables into one

Tags: mysql, join, merge

I have two tables, both share few columns. I want to join them, and merge the fields.

I want to query them both, and merge them into one row - using the latest data, based on the `created` field

example:

```
table1 [id, created, name, title, file, delete]
table2 [id, created, name, title, old, active]
# result
       [id, created, name, title, file, delete, old, active]
```

how can it be done?

Comment: Any query you have tried ?

Comment: No, i have no idea where to start.

Comment: Why don't you use inner join if the tables have relation on "created"?

Comment: @Tushar relation? meaning?
an inner join will simply join the tables, and will not filter out the undesired fields.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query you're looking for (considering that both ids are identical between both tables):

```
SELECT T1.id
    ,T1.created
    ,T1.name
    ,T1.title
    ,T1.file
    ,T1.delete
    ,T2.old
    ,T2.active
FROM table1 T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT TL.id
                ,MAX(TL.created) AS created
            FROM table1 TL
            GROUP BY TL.id) T ON T.id = T1.id
                                 AND T.created = T1.created
INNER JOIN table2 T2 ON T2.id = T1.id
                       AND T2.created = T1.created
```

The first `INNER JOIN` is used to keep only the most recent occurrence for each `id` (use of `GROUP BY` clause and `MAX` function).

Hope this will help.

Comment: The first join is required to keep only the most recent occurrence of each `id` (using `GROUP BY` clause and `MAX` function). By using an `INNER JOIN` i'm sure that i only keep the desired rows and the second jointure provide me the additional info i'm looking for (`old` and `active`)

Comment: @yossi Does the query return the result you're expecting? I added a brief explanation about the first `INNER JOIN` clause in order to make it more understandable

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT a.id, a.created, a.name, a.title, a.file, a.delete, b.old, b.active
FROM table1 a,
     table2 b
WHERE a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Don't use this old school syntax for the jointure, use explicit `JOIN` clause instead! And you're query doesn't provide the expected result: latest data based on the `created` field